# Returning undefined when fetching data from lumen api

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, lumen

I am using lumen as my api and access it through laravel using vue js. Please refer to the code below. When I console.log the books callback I am getting all the objects in the lumen api. However when i try to display it on my view page nothing display. Also when I console.log books.title i get undefined value. Any help will be appreciated.

```
Vue.component('bookmanager', {

    template: '#book-template',

    data: function(){
        return{
            books: []
        };
    },

    created: function(){
        $.ajax({

            url: "http://localhost/bookmanager/public/book",
            crossDomain: true
        }).done(function(books){
            this.books = books;
            console.log(books);
            console.log("success");
        }).fail(function(){
            console.log("error");
        });
    }
});

new Vue({

    el: 'body'

});
```

My index view page

```
<div class="container">
    <bookmanager></bookmanager>
</div>

<template id="book-template">

    <h1>Book Manager</h1>   
    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="book in books">
            @{{ book->title }}
        </li>

        <li class="list-group-item" v-for="book in books">
            @{{ book->isbn }}
        </li>
    </ul>

</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` inside your callback function for the `done` method of your ajax request does not refer to the `vm` instance. Try this

```
created: function(){
var vm = this;
$.ajax({

    url: "http://localhost/bookmanager/public/book",
    crossDomain: true
}).done(function(books){
    vm.$set('books', books);//or vm.books = books;
    console.log(books);
    console.log("success");
}).fail(function(){
    console.log("error");
});
```

}

I noticed you are using `book->title` instead of `book.title` inside your `v-for` loop

Comment: Ogie Thanks mate I'll try it later.